# HTTPS using Java Apache PostMethod

Tags: apache-commons-httpclient

When we upload the file using Apache PostMethod via HTTP file makes it fine to the server. If we upload it via HTTPS a corrupted OKB file is saved to the server. No errors in the log files.

Smaller 1KB files get uploaded correctly. What could be possible going on. We use JDK1.7, and Apache commons 3.1.

Any ideas will be appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure there aren't any errors?  They could be swallowed by a `try {} catch(Exception ex) {}`.

Comment: On further investigation with trace level set there were no errors. We were using commons-fileupload 1.2.jar, we had to upgrade that to commons-fileupload 1.2.2.jar to get it work with JDK 1.7 on the client side. Note the server was always 1.7. Not sure what underlying problem was , but the upgrade fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading to commond-fileupload-1.2.2.jar fixed the issue for us.